# OPTIONS request blocked google endpoints

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

While making a xhr request from my application browser sends OPTIONS request since i am using endpoints in my project i have all request that have api key with their requests therefore options request also contains api key.

For my api key i have set some http referers on cloud console

Therefore while making OPTIONS request it shows

```
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

and no referer is attached to my requests headers for OPTIONS request
hence it shows 403 error to my requests

Comment: What are you asking? I can't understand this question.

Comment: While applying api key restriction (HTTP referrers) in my endpoints api, the OPTIONS request are getting blocked by endpoints server, but without restriction it works well. Since OPTIONS request are handled by endpoints itself i do not have any control over it. Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: I think it is getting blocked because OPTIONS request is not adding referrer header in its request headers.

Comment: Endpoints blocks OPTIONS request by default. You have to allow cors. Here is the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/release-notes#january_2017. I'm assuming you've followed the steps because it works without restrictions, but can you confirm?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @WesleyWong, I am using app engine standard environment which uses endpoints frameworks where CORS traffic is already allowed. FYI, OPTIONS request are through if any sort of restriction is not applied to the API key but they get blocked if the API key restriction is applied to it. But still i tried the above solution but it didn't worked for me!!

Comment: What is applying the 'no-referrer-when-downgrade'? Are you saying the response to the OPTIONS preflight says this? You are making your requests to a https url, right?

Comment: @RoseDavidson yes i am making call from https to https only which should not apply 'no-referrer-when-downgrade'. I think browser is putting this up in OPTIONS request. FYI, i tried to replicate this issue in chrome, safari, firefox, edge, and explorer. Chrome, firefox and explorer were having the same problem, edge was sending the referrer in the header while 'no-referrer-when-downgrade' was still present in its OPTIONS request and worked fine. safari didn't even send the OPTIONS so it also worked fine.

Comment: Yes, it is the default behavior of browsers to set that Referrer policy. There is nothing Endpoints can do to change that behavior. You should read the standard docs about Referrer policy: https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: @RoseDavidson but the same works for google api's. If we try to call a google api eg. Drive API at that point of time the OPTIONS request behaves the same way (Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade) but at that point of time api key restriction works fine. But the same for endpoints fails.